# Is it possible to "return a getter" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like this:

```
function x(){
    var o = {};
    o.__defineGetter__('y', function(){
        return new Date();
    });

    return o.y;
}

var z = x();
console.log(z);
//Wait 1 second
console.log(z); //Date should be one second past the last printing
```

Of course, this doesn't work because o.y is evaluated when it is returned. I'm looking for a way to return a variable that acts as a getter. The following example gives me hope that something like this could be possible:

```
function x(context){
    //Bind the getter to the passed in scope
    context.__defineGetter__('y', function(){
        return new Date();
    });
}

x(this);
console.log(y);
//Wait 1 second
console.log(y); //Date is one second past last printing
```

Has anyone ever tried to do something like this?

Yes, I'm familiar with other ways to model similar behavior using different syntax. I just want this particular syntax to work for a special scenario.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function x(){
    var o = function() {};
    o.__proto__ = {
           valueOf:  function() { 
               return new Date().toString(); 
           }
     };

    return o;
}

var z = x(); 
console.log(z);  // Tue Mar 13 2012 14:10:10 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
setTimeout(function() { 
   console.log(z); // Tue Mar 13 2012 14:10:12 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
}, 2000);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. However, it would be simpler to just return an object with a "valueOf" property from function x(), eg. "function x() { return { valueOf: function () { ... } }; }"

Comment: Yes, I can be written in more ways and simpler ways. But I guess the reason for x() and the object definition inside is that o can have more methods and properties to it and they are all defined in the private context of x. x() just returns o that when printed shows the time (in that example), but you can also have o.speak() or something like that. So for the sake of the question, the answer should respect the context even if incomplete or seemingly useless or wrong.

Comment: Agreed. But what I meant was, there is no reason to use a function as the object to return and rely on \_\_proto\_\_ which has patchy browser support. The original question does not return a function object, so I think this just adds unnecessary noise.

Comment: This is a very clever solution which solves the example I gave. I forgot exactly what I was trying to do, but it dealt with https://github.com/scriby/asyncblock. So it was indeed a very niche/strange thing to try to do, but it had a specific purpose in the context of that module. This solution wouldn't have solved my overall need due to the usage of valueOf, but I'll give you points for answering the question I actually asked :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, you cannot assign a value to a variable that causes the variable to act like it is a function when accessed like a variable. The closest you can come, as you pointed out in your question, is to define an property with a getter function. You cannot create a local variable of a function that works as you describe.

You can however, define a function that defines a global property with a getter function (or, rather, a property on the global object) and make it look like you did what you wanted. For exmaple, in ES5, the following will create a global variable `y` that acts as you describe.

```
function x(n) { 
    Object.defineProperty(this, n, { 
        get: function() { 
            return new Date(); 
        }
    }); 
}

x('y')
```

Note this only works in non-strict mode. In strict mode, `this` is would have the value `undefined`.

Why you would want a variable to act like that I cannot fathom.

Comment: @nikc.org Thanks! But now that it is nicely formatted someone might actually try to use it. Yikes!

Comment: you can. try doing this. var x = {valueOf:function() {console.log("i should be a variable"); return Math.random() }}; console.log(10 * x);

Comment: That is very clever and darn close. However, it doesn't work for the case given, that is, "console.log(x);" prints "[object Object]" because passing x as a parameter doesn't force the valueOf() call. But it is still kinda cool!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when you're returning `o.y` in the first function, you're not returning the getter method, you're returning the Date object returned by invoking the getter method. You're then assigning that Date object to `z`, so every time you `console.log(z)`, you're logging that Date object, not invoking the function again.

In the second example, when you console.log(y), you're actually invoking the function each time.

A possible solution, though problably not what you're wanting to do, is to have the getter in the first example return a function. Then it would work.

```
function x(){
    var o = {};
    o.__defineGetter__('y', function(){
        return function() {
            return new Date();
        }
    });

    return o.y;
}

var z = x();

console.log(z());
//Wait 1 second

setTimeout( function() {
    console.log(z()); //Date is one second past last printing
}, 1000)
```

Getter methods are kind of a special case in Javascript because they invoke a function without the usual `()` at the end, which I suppose can be confusing because normally you'd expect `o.y` to return a function rather than invoke a function.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: If you're going to do that, please offer an explanation. If you've noticed something wrong, it's much more helpful to leave a comment.

Comment: Your `function x...` is teaching bad coding style, it should be replaced with just `var z = function () { return new Date() };`. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/vrtja/

Comment: That was code from the original poster, not mine. I copied what he wrote and changes a few lines. Please pay attention before down-voting.

Comment: I didn't down vote you but you should not let the question obscure the answer. As bennedich pointed out, there is a much simpler way to define such a function.

Comment: I disagree, bennedich unnecessarily added a variable to the global scope whereas my example kept it enclosed in a function.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but you were trying to correct his code. I wouldn't mind removing the downvote if you edit your answer. The important thing is we don't teach bad examples.

Comment: I actually removed a variable since both `x` and `z` can be replaced by just one variable referencing the function.

Comment: You didn't remove any variables; you added one. The OP had `x` and `z` and you had `x`, `z`, and `f`. Furthermore, the fiddle you linked to doesn't answer the OPs question, nor is it stylistically and better than my answer, which was written to help the OP understand what was going on, not to be a model of excellent Javascript coding style. It would have been inappropriate and unhelpful for me to stray from the point of my answer by commenting on the quality of his code. By having my return statement return a function, I believe I was helping illuminate was was actually going on.

Comment: Thanks. I do know the details of what's going on here, and I'm aware I can return a function to get similar behavior. I really do want the exact behavior I described. Basically, just assume I have a good reason for wanting to do it that way.

Comment: Wow, the point of my demo really went over your head. It points out that in the end `z === f` therefore you can replace it all with just an immediate function. Here's a new demo for you to grasp: http://jsfiddle.net/vrtja/1/. Stay classy.

Comment: @bennedich, if you think the OP wanted to know how to simply get a new Date, you've sorely missed the point. Also, you clearly don't know what an immediate function is. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449399115/functions/immediate_functions

Comment: Oh, didn't know those were called immediate functions, thx for sharing :)